# MoveDataPowerShellHost.exe missing from sbserver

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell, small-business

We are getting a lot of errors in our eventlog that indicates our sbsmonitoring DB is too big. I've had this once before, so I found a method to recreate that DB. In order to do that, I need a powershell tool called MoveDataPowerShellHost.exe which should be found in `C:\Program Files\Windows Small Business Server\Bin`. That was the case the previous time, but on this SBserver (2008), I cannot find that file.

This is the [original post](http://www.itquibbles.com/sql-sbsmonitoring-high-disk-usage/) on how to recreate the database.
When I search for powershell in the textbox when pressing start, I get these results:

[image]

These aren't the right exe files though.

Is there a way I can get MoveDataPowerShellHost installed on the server, or should that come pre-installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the inline comments of the `Create-SBSMonitoringDb.ps1` that is used to recreate the DB in the referred guide:

```
# In SBS 2011 std it requires Framework v4 Assemblies - Launch MoveDataPowerShellHost.exe as an admin from SBS BIN folder, then run this PS1
```

Indicating that the requirement to launch it from `MoveDataPowerShellHost.exe` is specific to SBS 2011.

You should be able to run it successfully on SBS 2008 from a "normal" `powershell.exe` host (still elevated/Run As Administrator of course)

---

The reason for this is that SBS 2008 and 2011 are both build on Windows Server 2008 R2 which ships with PowerShell 2.0 - PowerShell 2.0 itself runs inside the .NET **2.0** CLR - so if all the SBS code was ported to .NET **4.0** for the SBS 2011 release, you would need a .NET **4.0** host application. `MoveDataPowerShellHost.exe` is probably just that, possible an early PowerShell 3.0 build

Comment: Thanks, it also mentioned that for 2008, it could take up to 48 for the monitoring to work properly again, so will have to waita while to verify the proces was succesful, but procedure went as planned so thank you for the input.